# How to set markModified at object in array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an model User with inventory filed (it is an Array)
For example I have:

```
user: {
  inventory: [
    {
      item: 'somethink',
      status: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

So when I change my inventory varibale, i use markModified('inventory'), but what should I use when I change item in inventory? Because markModified('inventory') is not working for me.

Answer (score -2):

try to tell mongoose about item inside array that changed

```
user.markModified('inventory.item');  
// then save this:  
user.save();
```